# Nexus npm private registry configuration

Tags: npm, repository, nexus

I am using Nexus Repository ManagerOSS 3.0.2-0, I have successfully created npm hosted repository, but when I click on the link it always says 400 bad request.
And also through command line am not able to perform npm adduser pointing to this registry .
 Any idea what am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link in the UI is non functional, it's there to copy for use in setting up tooling, the 400 is expected behavior at this point in time.

As for npm adduser, I believe this should work. Make sure to have the npm Bearer Token Realm enabled.

You can read more about enabling it here: https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/npm.html#_authentication_using_realm_and_login

Comment: Thank you @DarthHater ,after setting Bearer Token Realm I was able to add user(I do not see any error after adduser) but when I try to add another user again that way ,it fails with npm ERR! registry error parsing json

Comment: Its finally working,those who are behind corporate fire wall,do not use http/https proxy if your registry is internal, because the way nexus behaves is strange when you set http proxy. it will not resolve internal IP address and finally times out with 408 status code